# Update pandas data into existing csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, azure-databricks

I have a csv which I'm creating from pandas data-frame.

But as soon as I append it, it throws: OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported

```
for single_date in [d for d in (start_date + timedelta(n) for n in range(day_count)) if d <= end_date]:
  currentDate = datetime.strftime(single_date,"%Y-%m-%d")
  #Send request for one day to the API and store it in a daily csv file
  response = requests.get(endpoint+f"?startDate={currentDate}&endDate={currentDate}",headers=headers)
  rawData = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.content.decode('utf-8')))


  outFileName = 'test1.csv'
  outdir = '/dbfs/mnt/project/test2/'
  if not os.path.exists(outdir):
    os.mkdir(outdir)

  fullname = os.path.join(outdir, outFileName)    


  pdf = pd.DataFrame(rawData)
  if not os.path.isfile(fullname):
    pdf.to_csv(fullname, header=True, index=False)
  else: # else it exists so append without writing the header
    with open(fullname, 'a') as f: #This part gives error... If i write 'w' as mode, its overwriting and working fine.
      pdf.to_csv(f, header=False, index=False, mode='a')
```

Comment: Not sure if this is any help, but on several occasions I read that pandas' file methods shouldn't get handles, but filenames/paths instead. Besides, with this you won't need the context manager, since the function itself is responsible for closing (if you give it a path).

Comment: @OlegO I already tried not using context manager. But its the same error.

Comment: I didn't understand this line:
pdf.to_csv(f, header=True, index=False)

what's f in here?

Comment: @OlegO sry i think i wrote wrong. Just corrected the first pdf.to_csv

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it because you opened the file in an append mode and then you are passing `mode = 'a'` again in your call to `to_csv`. Can you try simply do that?

```
pdf = pd.DataFrame(rawData)
if not os.path.isfile(fullname):
    pdf.to_csv(fullname, header=True, index=False)
else: # else it exists so append without writing the header
    pdf.to_csv(fullname, header=False, index=False, mode='a')
```

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work out, with appending. So I created parque files and then read them as data frame.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and the root cause was **Databrick Runtime > 6** does not support **append or random write** operation on the files which exist in DBFS. It was working fine for me until I updated my runtime from **5.5 to 6** as they suggested to do this because they were no longer supporting Runtime < 6 at that time.

I followed this workaround, read the file in code, appended the data, and overwritten it.